# Websocket not working with spring boot application and angular frontend

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, jhipster, sockjs

I looked and tried a lot but I can not find the cause of my problem...
I have a JHipster generated application which consists out of a spring boot application and an angular frontend and I want to use websockets for updates. For that I use Stomp and SockJs

The connection itself is already not working.
I get the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9000/updates/websocket/447/xxudq4ni/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

This is the call to port 9000, which is then proxied to the actual backend under Port 8080.
If I call the backend under port 8080 directly, I get:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/updates/websocket/156/mg0dspp2/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

I do not really see what the actual response is but I suppose it is the JHIpster error message "an error has occured" and this html is returned with a http statuscode of 200.

I'm out of ideas what the actual problem is... I followed this [intro here](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring) and several others...
here is my backend:

**WebsocketConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    public static final String IP_ADDRESS = "IP_ADDRESS";

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addEndpoint("/updates/websocket")
            //.setHandshakeHandler(defaultHandshakeHandler())
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS()
            .setClientLibraryUrl("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1.5.0/dist/sockjs.min.js");
            //.setInterceptors(httpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
    }

    private DefaultHandshakeHandler defaultHandshakeHandler() {
        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler() {
            @Override
            protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
                Principal principal = request.getPrincipal();
                if (principal == null) {
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ANONYMOUS));
                    principal = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("WebsocketConfiguration", "anonymous", authorities);
                }
                return principal;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public HandshakeInterceptor httpSessionHandshakeInterceptor() {
        return new HandshakeInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public boolean beforeHandshake(
                ServerHttpRequest request,
                ServerHttpResponse response,
                WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                Map<String, Object> attributes
            ) throws Exception {
                if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
                    ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
                    attributes.put(IP_ADDRESS, servletRequest.getRemoteAddress());
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterHandshake(
                ServerHttpRequest request,
                ServerHttpResponse response,
                WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                Exception exception
            ) {}
        };
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class UpdateController  {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UpdateController.class);
    
    @MessageMapping("/updates/websocket")
    @SendTo("/topic/trucks")
    public UpdateDto send(UpdateDto dto) {
        return dto;
    }
}
```

**Frontend:**

```
 connect(): void {
        if (this.stompClient?.connected || this.called) {
            return;
        }
        this.called = true;
        // building absolute path so that websocket doesn't fail when deploying with a context path
        let url = '/updates/websocket';
        url = this.location.prepareExternalUrl(url);

        var socket = new SockJS(url);
        this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        this.stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
            this.connectionSubject.next();

            this.sendActivity();

            this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
                .pipe(filter((event: Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
                .subscribe(() => this.sendActivity());
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Im on Windows and I use Chrome for the development. But it also does not work in FireFox, so I do not think it has something to do with the platform.
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: An error with status code 200 is strange anyway.. However: your config looks good and similar to mine, except the setClientLibraryUrl. One idea to check: Jhipster creates a SecurityConfiguration that defines who may access an endpoint. And your endpoint (updates/**) should be accessible by the current user (or you may use permitAll)?!

Comment: Do you have this change in your code? Otherwise the websocket endpoint is sent to `/index.html` In your case it may need to be `updates` instead of `websocket` since it differs from JHipster's websocket implementation https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/6ce5d7e6ea69d5953ef849e06654d8740531b73d/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/web/rest/ClientForwardController.java.ejs#L32